# Apply italic formatting to every other row

Tags: tables

How can I make every second row in the following table in italics?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
45.1 &22.3\\
15000.9999 & 23568.44485\\
45.1 &22.3\\
15000.9999 & 23568.44485\\
45.1 &22.3\\
15000.9999 & 23568.44485\\
45.1 &22.3\\
15000.9999 & 23568.44485\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, with `etoolbox` and `array`: I create a `rowcnt` counter initialise it at the beginning of the tabular environment and reset it at the end. A `\altshape` command is executed at the beginning of each cell, the result of which depends on the parity of `rowcnt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor, etoolbox, dcounter}
\newcounter{rowcnt}
\newcommand\altshape{\ifnumodd{\value{rowcnt}}{\color{red}}{\itshape}}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\altshape}l}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcnt}{1}}
\AtEndEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcnt}{0}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\therowcnt\quad}LL<{\stepcounter{rowcnt}}}
  45.1 & 22.3 \\
  15000.9999 & 23568.44485 \\
  45.1 & 22.3 \\
  15000.9999 & 23568.44485 \\
  45.1 & 22.3 \\
  15000.9999 & 23568.44485 \\
  45.1 & 22.3 \\
  15000.9999 & 23568.44485 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I surround the \itshape command with the following code in order to round the numbers to the nearest integer? I can't get it to work. `\num[round-precision=0,group-separator={,},round-mode=places]{}`

Comment: You can obtain this result, but will have to insert a `\num` command in each cell.

Comment: Thanks. The example above isn't working when I load it into a larger document with more `\usepackage` commands. I'm getting a `Package array Error: <{..} at wrong position`. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using the [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) package:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    postproc cell content/.code={
        \ifodd\pgfplotstablerow\relax
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content={\itshape#1}}%
        \fi
    },
]{45.1 22.3
    15000.9999  23568.44485
    45.1 22.3
    15000.9999  23568.44485
    45.1 22.3
    15000.9999  23568.44485
    45.1 22.3
    15000.9999  23568.44485
}
\end{document}
```

I used [Pgfplotstable and multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106504/pgfplotstable-and-multirow) as a starting point.

Comment: I can't seem to replace the raw data with a call to `\input` to import some data from a csv file. . .